# Detect external user and ask for password before opening book

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a short code so that it can detect an external user and ask for a password, but I don't know how to avoid saving messages.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False

If Application.UserName = "User1" Or Application.UserName = "User2" Then
    Welc = MsgBox("Welcome " & Application.UserName)
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
    Exit Sub
Else
    Pass = "1973"
    Prompt = "Enter the password to continue"
    Title = "Password Input"
    UserPass = InputBox(Prompt, Title)
    If UserPass <> Pass Then
        Prompt = "You have entered an incorrect password"
        Title = "Incorrect Passowd"
        MsgBox Prompt, vbCritical, Title
        ThisWorkbook.Close
        Exit Sub
    Else
    Welc = MsgBox("Welcome " & Application.UserName)
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use Excel's built in password to access?

Comment: Does that detect users? I've only used it to always ask for a password.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt know about `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If Application.UserName = "User1" Or Application.UserName = "User2" Then
    Welc = MsgBox("Welcome " & Application.UserName)
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub
Else
    Pass = "1973"
    Prompt = "Enter the password to continue"
    Title = "Password Input"
    UserPass = InputBox(Prompt, Title)
    If UserPass <> Pass Then
        Prompt = "You have entered an incorrect password"
        Title = "Incorrect Passowd"
        MsgBox Prompt, vbCritical, Title
        ThisWorkbook.Close
        Exit Sub
    Else
    Welc = MsgBox("Welcome " & Application.UserName)
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think pretty much anyone with a rating of 1k or higher on this board could get around your "security". Disable macros on open... written in plain text... Maybe your not dealing with very sophisticated users, so it may work. But if you're seriously trying to prevent some data or the file, this method should not be considered robust.

Comment: Im not dealing with macro users, but its the only way i now :(